# iOS - Multiple UITableViews?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm doubtful about which is the best way to show multiple UITableViews.

My first approach is to subclass UITableViewController and simulate 3 UITableViews with 3 sections and 3 headers each, and control the data with the indexPath.section property of the delegate protocol.

My second approach is to subclass UIViewController and add 3 UITableViews and control the data with the tableView property of the delegate protocol.

I have made both and they look very similar, it turns out that the UITableViewController subclass is a little bit more difficult to give spacing and UI-like stuff. But in general one can achieve the same purpose.

So, is one or another the "best" way to achieve this scenario or what difference have you found with one or another?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've answered your own question here. `UITableViewController` is meant to interact with its built in `tableView`, while `UIViewController` probably more naturally allows for you to add as many as you want. In the future, try to ask a more specific question, as this one is very opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both approaches, however with multiple table views you will lose one important `UITableView` feature - cell reusing.

If you have no scrolling (table views are small or static) then there is no problem. However, if you are putting all 3 tables into one scrollview and there is a lot of items, the table views are always rendered in full height and all their cells are rendered together.

This can negatively affect rendering performance, especially if one of your tables is loading data dynamically from database (e.g. Core Data).

With static or small tables, there is no real difference.

Also note that `UITableViewController` has additional helpful properties - e.g. pull to refresh view.

Comment: Why would you lose the ability to reuse cells?

Comment: @Paulw11 once table view is put inside a scrollview (table view does not scroll, its parent view is scrolling) it loses the ability to track which cells are visible on the screen. It actually thinks the whole table is visible and all cells are displayed at once. Hence they are not reused because all cells are always visible.

Comment: Ok, but nothing was said about using a scroll view.  One solution was to use a section for each "table" the other was multiple tableviews in a view

Comment: @Paulw11 As I said "if you have no scrolling, then there is no problem" and "if you are putting all 3 tables into one scrollview..." Using one parent scroll view for multiple separate table views is a common pattern.

Comment: But you only lose cell reuse if you put all 3 tableviews into a scrollview, which wasn't a suggestion of the OP nor outlined in your answer.  If you allow all 3 tables to scroll independently then there is no issue with reuse

Comment: @Sulthan Your assertion about what happens to a table view inside a scroll view is untrue. The table view still has a fixed sized frame with the parent scroll view that only shows a limited number of rows. The table view will still work as it normally would based on what rows are currently showing within that frame. It doesn't matter whether or not that portion of the scroll view is in view on the screen or not.

Comment: @rmaddy A table view inside a scroll view has a fixed size frame but its height must be equal to table's content height, otherwise scrolling won't work in the scroll view. That means all table cells are rendered at once and no reusing can happen.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use tableview tag. and check conditions by tag. for datasource and delegate. In my current project I have min 3 tableview and 3 collection view in one controller.